# WPF: Getting row header of selected cells

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, selection

So I have a filled **datagrid** with some values. I have some selected **cells** and what I need is to get the **column** and **row header** of each cell.

I have found out how to get the column header easily, but the row one doesn't want to come to me so easy...

#### My code of getting the values:

```
string[,] matrix = new string[2, 4];
```

^ I have maximum of 4 selected cells - I want to keep the value of their headers(row + column) as strings.

```
IList<DataGridCellInfo> theChosenOnes = mydatagrid.SelectedCells;

int c = 0;

foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in theChosenOnes)
    {
       matrix[1,c] = cell.Column.Header.ToString();
```

^ this gives me what I want - the string that the column header of this cell contains

```
       matrix[0,c] = cell.Item.ToString();
```

^ this gives me - "System.Data.DataRowView"

```
       c++;
    }
```

Also I should add information that I'm using `SelectionMode="Extended"` + `SelectionUnit="Cell"` + my datagrid has both row and column headers - need those values.

I was looking at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellinfo.aspx but it says I can get a Row from there but Visual Studio ain't letting me do that (tried something like: `matrix[0,c] = cell.Row.Header.ToString();` )

Also checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx .. and tried working with those properties, but it won't work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** I "upgraded" the code with something I found here but it still doesn't give me what I want :|

```
matrix[0, c] = ((DataRowView)cell.Item).Row.ToString();
```

^ now I can get the [row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)(as "System.Data.DataRow").. but why can't I get the row header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be weird but I finally found the answer on my own.. :D (as long as noone else wanted to help me :'( ..)

It might be a long/weird/notbest solution, but it's working as I want it. So if u guys have better solution tell me :]

Found this link: http://techiethings.blogspot.in/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

So I decided to get the row index:

instead:

```
matrix[0,c] = cell.Item.ToString();
```

I used this:

myArray[] = {my row header values};

```
matrix[0,c] = myArray[((DataGridRow)mydatagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cell.Item)).GetIndex()] ;
```

It works as I need so I'm satisfied. If u see anything wrong or better solution, add answer/comments please.